# MySQL mysqldump from Java code on Win7 issues

Tags: java, windows, mysql, runtime.exec

Ok, my Java application is not able to perform a mysqldump backup using the windows runtime enviroment. I have printout code for caught exceptions and I see no exceptions being thrown, looks fine on the surface when the backup code is executed.

I have also tested the mysqldump command in the command-line console; and it works with no issue there.

Code:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    Process pr = rt.exec("mysqldump -u test --password=pass lager > newBackup.sql");

} catch (IOException ex) {
     System.out.println("IO error Runtime.  "+ex.getMessage());
}
```

Does anyone know why it will not dump/backup the database? Is there some permission I need to add or something (running windows 7).

Comment: You're printing `ex.getMessage ()` but you're not telling us what it says ?

Comment: Thats the thing, it doesn't throw any exception. It used to when I got the command wrong, or didn't have mysqldump as a PATH variable. Just no files are being outputted, and I don't know why since there are no feedback.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could look over this article about the difference beetwen exec et the command line(http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html).

On my side I try this code that work to capture the output of mysqldump --help command with the Class StreamGoggle find into the article from javaworld:

```
    public Main() {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:/tmp/test.txt");
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec("mysqldump --help");
        // any error message?
        StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(
                proc.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");

        StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(
                proc.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT", fos);

        errorGobbler.start();
        outputGobbler.start();

        int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
        System.out.println("ExitValue: " + exitVal);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```